# How to install Let's Encrypt SSL on reverse proxied server?

Tags: ssl, https, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

So I created an Ubuntu 16.04 droplet in DigitalOcean and used ServerPilot to set it up. ServerPilot automatically creates a webserver on top of your Ubuntu using Apache and nginx as reverse proxy.

Now I'm not sure how I can go about installing Let's Encrypt SSL on a reverse proxy server. Do I have to run Certbot for nginx since nginx serves the frontend? I'm trying to be able to use HTTPS to access my site.

Is procedure different for reverse proxy servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no difference. You can either use the webroot of Apache or include a rule in Nginx to answer all ACME challenge requests directly.

**Example**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                root /tmp;
        }
}
```

Then use `/tmp` or any other path for your challenges. Personally, I use my own client written in PHP and much simpler than the official one. See https://github.com/kelunik/acme-client.